# how do i do a quick loop here

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
Array
(
[product_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 61
        [1] => 62
        [2] => 63
    )

[product_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 44" jesson WIDESCREEN LCD 
        [1] => 19" jesson WIDESCREEN LCD 
        [2] => Touchscreen monitor
    )

)
```

I am sort of confused on how to do this simple loop where product_id[0] always matches product_name[0] and so on ....i tried

if i do a foreach i get the first loop is all the product_id and i need the names to be printed also....any ideas

Comment: Don't you want product_name to be indexed by product_id? E.g. 61 => 44" jesson WIDESCREEN LCD, 62 => 19" jesson WIDESCREEN LCD, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ease of explanation, let's set:

```
$product_id = $myarray['product_id'];
$product_name = $myarray['product_name'];
```

As long as you're sure that `$product_id` and `$product_name` have the same keys (and it looks like they do), you can make your loop like this:

```
foreach ($product_id as $i => $id) {
  $name = $product_name[$i];
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

Comment: '$name' will constantly overwrite itself.

Comment: Also, the original question has the two arrays nested in another array, so your syntax should reflect that.

Comment: $product_id and $product_name are elements of the outer array, not separate variables

Comment: Fixed that.  Could just as easily use `foreach ($myarray['product_id'] as $i => $id)` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array['product_id'] as $k=>$v){
    echo $v." - ".$array['product_name'][$k];
}
```

This will echo out the product  id, followed by the corresponding product name. You can change that to do what you like but the important values are there.

Comment: I'd quote the key names, e.g. $array['product_id'], to avoid notices about undefined constants

Comment: `product_id` and `product_name` should be quoted (will throw a notice).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array['product_id'] as $key => $prodid) {
  $prodname = $array['product_name'][$key];

  //do what you want with $prodid and $prodname here
}
```